# How to take a different action for every position in ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

i would like to make a different action(maybe Intent) for every item in ListView rather than Toast, Thanks.

**this is my java code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Array of strings...
        final String[] mobileArray = {"Android", "IPhone", "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry",
                "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X"};


        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                                    long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hello world", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });
     }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Notes for future please ask the question before the code so people don't have to search for your questions, secondly don't just past code into SO please use code wrap around the code in question

Comment: thank you  @MartinBarker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use position for doing different things on different lines in your listView.setOnItemClickListener like this

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                            long id) {
       switch (position){
             case 0:
             // your code here
             break;
             case 1:
             // your code
             break;
             ..... so on
        }


        }
    });
```

Comment: The id might also be a good choice if it is available, and it would be more robust to position changes in the list. Edit : Nevermind, missed the adapter part in the code.

Comment: welcome @hossamrakha if your ques is solved then mark it as answer so that the ques can be closed

Comment: sorry but i have no reputation how can i accept  it as answer ? @Anmol

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function that recive position as it parameter

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                                                                    long id) {

                                                doSomething(position);

                                            }
                                            public void doSomething(int position){

                                                switch(position)
                                                {
                                                    case 1:
                                                        //do this
                                                        break;
                                                    case 2:
                                                        //do this
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            }});
```